# Finding best conditional logistic regression model with unbalanced strata

Tags: logistic, lasso, epidemiology, case-control-study, clogit

I am interested in fitting the best possible model for the case of conditional logistic regression where the strata are unbalanced. Although I have not seen it specified, but I understand that there is no problem in having unbalanced strata for `survival::clogit` and `Epi::clogistic`. Is this right?

To find the best model, would it be correct to use a stepwise selection? That is, removing or adding variables as a function of the likelihood ratio test measure. Or should the LASSO criterion be used? 
The most recent package I've seen is `clogitLasso` but I couldn't find a 1:M stratum option.